# Ajax.ActionLink triggering from Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, razor

I am successfully using @Ajax.ActionLink to refresh data on a portion of my page, but I would like to do the same from Javascript.  How can I simulate the effects of clicking that ActionLink in js?

Thanks!

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("ClickMe", "List", "Organizations", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "dashboardDetails"})
```

Comment: Very old question, but in need of an update. As you are using `Ajax.ActionLink`, you can simply trigger that link from JQuery. Example added below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at using the [$.get()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) and [.$post()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) jQuery functions. So basically, you can perform a call to a controller action, from Javascript, using either of these functions (depending on whether your getting or posting data).

An example can be found [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/srkirkland/archive/2009/09/08/using-jquery-ajax-methods-in-asp-net-mvc-get-and-getjson-vs-post.aspx).

Comment: Thank you Jason, $.get() appears to handle what I need to do.

Answer (score 2):

Behind the scenes Unobtrusive,JQuery simply matches on the ajax links with `a[data-ajax=true]` and runs this code:

```
$(document).on("click", "a[data-ajax=true]", function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    asyncRequest(this, {
        url: this.href,
        type: "GET",
        data: []
    });
});
```

`asyncRequest` simply runs an $.ajax call with all the options assembled for it.

You can get the same effect by simply sending a click to your link. Assuming you give your link an id with the optional HtmlAttributes like this:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("ClickMe", "List", "Organizations", New AjaxOptions With {.UpdateTargetId = "dashboardDetails"}, new { id = "myajaxLink" })
```

you can simply trigger it with:

```
$('#myajaxLink').click();
```

Answer (score 0):

JQuery has extensive support for ajax calls.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

also check this blog out

[Using jQuery ajax to load a partial view in ASP.NET MVC 2 and then retrieve the input on the server again](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingJQueryAjaxToLoadAPartialViewInASPNETMVC2AndThenRetrieveTheInputOnTheServerAgain.aspx)