# Equivalent of Ajax.ActionLink with Route Values from javascript in master/detail scenario

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a master/detail scenario where the master is a grid and the detail is a partial view.  I can add a column in the table with the following code to load the detail via ajax when clicked:

```
 @Ajax.ActionLink(("details", "ViewDetails", new { id = item.Id}, new AjaxOptions { 
            UpdateTargetId="ProjectDetails", 
            Url=Url.Action("ViewDetails"), 
            LoadingElementId="ProjectDetailsLoading", 
            LoadingElementDuration=2000 })
```

But what if I want to show the detail on row select?  Well, I have an OnRowSelected() event I can hook on the client, and pull out the Id I need to send back to the ViewDetails action as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function onRowSelected(e) {
    ID = e.row.cells[0].innerHTML; 

    // now what?  How do I form the equivalent of Ajax.ActionLink?
}
</script>
```

This post: [Ajax.ActionLink triggering from Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6310289/ajax-actionlink-triggering-from-javascript) shows how to use $.get() to trigger an ajax postback, but it doesn't show how to specify everything (including the Id I need to send) in the server-side equivalent.  Thanks for your help, and I'm sure your solution will help a lot of people, too!

Answer (score 0):

No idea what grid and what `onRowSelected` event you are talking about, but you could use HTML5 data-* attributes inside the first cell of your *grid*. For example you could put a hidden div or directly inside the corresponding `<tr>` if you have control over its rendering. Actually all you need here is the url of the action.

So here's an example with a hidden div that you could put inside the first cell of each row:

```
<div style="display:none;" data-url="@Url.Action("details", "ViewDetails", new { id = item.Id })"></div>
```

and then it's easy:

```
function onRowSelected(e) {
    var url = $('div', e.row.cells[0]).data('url');
    $('#ProjectDetailsLoading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            $('#ProjectDetails').html(result);
        }
        complete: function() {
            $('#ProjectDetailsLoading').hide();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: This is brilliant, I will give it a try!  Actually, the grid is a telerik mvc3 grid, but I think I can get it to do this, too.